# blazor WASM new select options refresh slower than assignment of new bind value

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a select dropdown which I populate content for via a foreach loop off of a list. In one circumstance I want to be able to add a new option to that list and then select that new option. I'm able to add the new value to the list and I'm able to assign the binded property it's new value. I have comments in the output which show the variables are as they should be.

However the UI is not updating prior to the binded property attempting to trigger an on change event leading to the select not selecting the new value but instead what ever the first value of the list is.

I've tried calling stateHasChanged() immediately after updating the list but that doesn't seem to change anything. The specific scenarios logic is occurring in an async Task fired from a button click.

Logic to update the list:

```
async Task SaveProfile(){
   Profiles.Insert(Profiles.Count - 1, new TableConfiguration() { ConfigurationId = NewProfile });
   StateHasChanged();
   ProfileDecode = NewProfile;
}
```

Select UI Logic:

```
<select @bind=ProfileDecode class="form-control-sm">
            @foreach (var prof in Profiles)
            {
                <option>@prof.ConfigurationId</option>
            }
        </select>
```

ProfileDecode property

```
private string ProfileDecode
        {
            get { return SelectedProfile.ConfigurationId; }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("passed value:" + value + " current value:" + ProfileDecode);
                if (SelectedProfile.ConfigurationId != value)
                {
                    
                    SelectedProfile = Profiles.Single(p => p.ConfigurationId == value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm struggling a little to put together a working model based on the code snippets you've provided.  Someone else may figure it out: if they do I'll happily delete this answer.

So, I've built what I believe is a basic replica of what you are trying to achieve as a single Razor page.

This works.  If this doesn't properly mimic what you have, please alter it so that it does, so we can help get to the bottom of the problem.

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<select @bind="selectedItem" class="form-select">
    @foreach (var country in Countries)
    {
        if (country == selectedItem) selectCountry = true;
        else selectCountry = false;
       
        <option @key= "country" selected="@selectCountry" value=country>@country</option>

}
</select>


<div class="m-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <input class="form-control form-text" type="text" @bind-value=this.newCountry />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.AddToList>Add To List</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string selectedItem = string.Empty;

    private string newCountry = string.Empty;
    private bool selectCountry = false;


    private List<string> Countries = new List<string> { "UK", "France", "Spain" };

    private async Task AddToList()
    {
        // mimic some async action such as a Db or api get
        await Task.Delay(100);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.newCountry))
        {
            //Countries.Add(newCountry);

            Countries.Insert(Countries.Count - 1, newCountry);
            selectedItem = newCountry;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey so I can't seem to edit your comment right now but I agree that the code you have works as I'd want it to. However, can you try and replace your Countries.Add(newCountry) with Countries.Insert(Countries.Count - 1, newCountry). I did this myself and the issue seems to show up after the second insert occurs.

Comment: `the issue seems to show up after the second insert occurs` This is different issue, solved by adding the `@key` directive

Comment: Yeah the key does seem to solve this. Do you know what the difference is in this case between Add and @Key with insert?

Comment: The `@key` is a helper for the Renderer to identify items in  list when they get re-organised, as in adding an item somewhere in the list, rather than at the end.  Anyway, solved your problem, Bon voyage!